# Get data attributes from object in list in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dataset, custom-data-attribute

I have a list of objects

```
[Object, Object, Object]
```

Each objects has

```
Object {x: 1, y: 0, width: 4, height: 5, max_width: undefined…}
```

and some other parameters. Each object is a `<div>` element with data attributes `<div id="panel" data-panel-id="2">`. How can I get the value of `data-panel-id`?

I have tried

```
items.forEach(function (item) {
  console.log(item);
  console.log(item.el);
  console.log(item.el.firstNode);
  console.log(item.el.firstNode.dataset);
```

etc.

I think it would work if I used `document.getElementById("panel").dataset.panelId` but my list contains objects and not html elements, so I don't know how to do it.

My list of objects is created from gridstack.js library (https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js) in an onChange listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never worked on this library but I just checked the library and found that every item object has it's DOM node in `el` attribute. So we can data set following way:

```
    items.forEach(function (item) {
     var panelId =  item.el[0].dataset['panelId'] //el[0] --> Since el is a jQuery object we need to get it's javascript object.

     //If you want to use jQuery:
     var panelId =  item.el.data('panelId');
    }
```